# Find index of first non-null element in multiple lists

Tags: c#

I have a few IEnumerable of nullable Doubles:

```
IEnumerable<Double?> X = new List<Double> { null, 2.2, 4.4, 5.5, 3.2 }

IEnumerable<Double?> Y = new List<Double> { null, null, 4.4, 5.5 }
```

I need to find the maximum index of the first non-null element in both lists, e.g:

```
- Index of First non-null element in X: 1  < Value 2.2

- Index of First non-null element in Y: 2  < Value 4.4
```

So the maximum index in both lists would be 2.

I am finding the indexes the following way:

```
Int32? indexOfFirstNonNullX = X.Select((Input, Index) => new { Value, Index }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value != null)?.Index;

Int32? indexOfFirstNonNullY = X.Select((Input, Index) => new { Value, Index }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value != null)?.Index;

Int32? indexOfFirstNonNullInXAndY = Math.Max(indexOfFirstNonNullX, indexOfFirstNonNullY);
```

**Question**

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Somethings I need to do this in 6 lists ...

Comment: frame challenge: I'd already track them as they're added. otherwise, solid and concise approach already. if there's no performance problem, I'd stick with that...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindIndex_System_Predicate__0__?

Comment: yes but that's specifically for `List` and would not generalize to `IEnumerable`

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface Yes, but then again, the entire question of finding indices is kind of pointless with `IEnumerable`. If you are going to be feeding them to `ElementAt()`, then really you want a list to begin with.

Comment: right... still, it is valid to ask for the number of items to enumerate until the first non-null is encountered and call that an "index" of sorts

Comment: I think @GSerg is correct.  The code, as written, is working with an `IEnumerable<T>`, after creating a `List<T>`.  The problem has already been solved if you throw away the `IEnumerable<T>` and promote it to a `List<T>`.

Comment: What if list1 has a match at index 0 and list2 at index 1 but list1 has only one item? You can't say that the min-match-index of both lists is 1 if not all lists have at least two items, can you?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could create an extension if you need it often:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int FindCommonMinIndexWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        int commonMinIndex = -1;
        foreach(var seq in sequences)
        {
            int minIndex = seq.Select((item, index) => (item, index))
                              .Where(x => predicate(x.item))
                              .Select(x => x.index)
                              .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
                              .First();
            if(minIndex == -1) return -1; // not found
            if(minIndex > commonMinIndex) commonMinIndex = minIndex;
        }
        
        return commonMinIndex;
    }
}
```

Now your code becomes a one-liner:

```
IEnumerable<double?> X = new List<double?> { null, 2.2, 4.4, 5.5, 3.2 };
IEnumerable<double?> Y = new List<double?> { new double?(), new double?(), 4.4, 5.5 };


IEnumerable<double?>[] allLists = {X, Y};
int commonMinIndex = allLists.FindCommonMinIndexWhere(d => d.HasValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to do this is using Zip:

```
IEnumerable<double?> x = new List<double?> { null, 2.2, 4.4, 5.5, 3.2 };
IEnumerable<double?> y = new List<double?> { null, null, 4.4, 5.5 };
IEnumerable<double?> z = new List<double?> { 1, null, null, 4.4, 5.5 };

var result = x
    .Zip(y, (a,b) => new List<double?>{a,b})
    .Zip(z, (a,b) => a.Append(b)) //repeat his line for each list after the second one
    .Select((element,index) => new {Element=element,Index=index})
    .Where(t => t.Element.All(e=>e!=null))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Results in:

```
Element
  5.5 
  5.5
  4.4
Index = 3
```

Edit: This also solves a issue in your original code, where if you have the following lists:

```
IEnumerable<Double?> X = new List<Double> { 2.2, 4.4, null, 5.5, 3.2 }
IEnumerable<Double?> Y = new List<Double> { null, null, 4.4, 5.5 }
```

Your code would return index 2, but you said you wanted the *first non-null element in both lists*, so we should return index 3.

Comment: and now with 10 lists ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter oh yeah, just saw OP last line about 6 lists... Well, I will leave this answer here if someone needs this for only 2 lists. For more than 2 lists, I think the best approach would be a loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter modified to take account multiple lists

Answer (score 0):

You can get a count of the initial nulls using [`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=net-5.0). Because of base-zero indexing, the count of initial nulls is equal to the index of the first non-null element.

```
IEnumerable<Double?> X = new List<Double> { null, 2.2, 4.4, 5.5, 3.2 }
var indexForX = X.TakeWhile( x => x == null ).Count();

IEnumerable<Double?> Y = new List<Double> { null, null, 4.4, 5.5 }
var indexForY = Y.TakeWhile( y => y == null ).Count();
```

If you have 6 lists (or more) I suggest using an array of lists.

```
var arrayOfLists = new IEnumerable<Double?>[] { X, Y, etc };
```

Then to get the max

```
var maxIndex = arrayOfLists.Max( list => list.TakeWhile( i => i == null ).Count() );
```